# How to compare class definitions in rails rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, rspec

I've created a gem that houses some generic code and executes a common set of functions on the given classes. We set the class name in a rails config initializer, like so.

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

Rails.application.config.my_gem = {
  # The gem uses the Rails.application.config.my_gem[:my_app_class] to execute functions in My::App::Klass.
  my_app_class: My::App::Klass
}
```

I'm trying to test that the class set in the configuration is the desired class

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "My Gem Configuration" do
  describe "Rails.application.config.my_gem" do
    let(:config) { Rails.application.config.my_gem }

    it "has my_app_class" do
      #FAILS
      #  expected My::App::Klass
      #  got My::App::Klass
      expect(config[:my_app_class]).to eq(My::App::Klass)

      #FAILS
      #  expected #<Class:18240> => My::App::Klass(id: string, name: string)
      #  got #<Class:15960> => My::App::Klass(id: string, name: string)
      expect(config[:my_app_class]).to be(My::App::Klass)

      #PASSES
      # My::App::Klass.inspect #=> My::App::Klass(id: string, name: string)
      expect(config[:my_app_class].inspect).to be(My::App::Klass.inspect)
    end
  end
end
```

Is the only way to compare definitions of classes (not instance of or kind of) to use inspect?

---

My environment

```sh
$> sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.7
BuildVersion:   19H1217
$> asdf version
v0.8.0-c6145d0
$> ruby -v
ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-darwin19]
$> rails -v
Rails 6.1.4.1
$> rspec -v
RSpec 3.10
  - rspec-core 3.10.1
  - rspec-expectations 3.10.1
  - rspec-mocks 3.10.2
  - rspec-rails 4.1.2
  - rspec-support 3.10.2
```

Comment: Your initial test passes for me `expect(config[:my_app_class]).to eq(My::App::Klass)` - gist -https://gist.github.com/allcentury/e6be6b1cfa2d5bcb2ac73bbba725885b

Comment: @Anthony Your script, in my env, outside of rails, passes! I wonder if RoR is doing something to the class definitions. More investigation is needed...

Comment: When I run `Rails.application.config.integrations` in my Rails6 env I get method_missing  errror. Is it something that is provided by another gem? Also: if you add config via `Rails.application.config.integrations` why don't you read this config in your test like `let(:config) { Rails.application.config.my_gem }` ? (I'm a noob in this area, forgive me if I'm missing sth obvious)

Comment: @Grzegorz Fixed the example. Should have been `Rails.application.config.my_gem`. The `my_gem` config is custom to my application. You could name it anything you want.